# Page Viewer Web Part navigation

Tags: hyperlink, iframe, page-viewer-web-part

I have a Sharepoint page with a page viewer web part plus multiple web parts.
The page viewer web part includes a PowerPoint graphic with hyperlinks.

I want to use the the PowerPoint presentation as in-page navigation, i.e. jump to a specific DIV.
Usually it is possible by defining links like
`my-site/my-page.aspx#divID` to jump to a div within the same page.
But unfortunately that is not possible.

Any suggestions how to use my included PowerPoint slide as in-page navigation?

**Update**

I found the reason for my problem:
The method I mentioned above actually works, but with one big limitation:

I assigned a hyperlink **to a shape** with text but **not to the text itself**.
Because of that, the link only works properly on the area around the text.
After also assigning a link to the text itself, my problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

The page viewer loads into an iFrame.  I would think you would need some fancy javascript on both the parent page and the iframe content.  You could then call into the parent and activate the functions.  If the content is not hosted on SharePoint you might some XSS issues.

```
Parent:

functon next(){
  Do something
} 

In the iFrame:
<a onclick="parent.next();" href="#" >Activate Div</a>
```

Comment: Very interesting approach! Is there a way to do that by just setting `href`? Maybe with a GET-Parameter?
It is not possible to set `onclick` in PowerPoint and I don't want to edit the output HTML.

Comment: Not on its own. The href would only work for content in scope which would be the PowerPoint iframe. You could use JavaScript to reference the output and inject the code you need so you don't have to alter the original code.  You can use JQuery .contents method to access iframe.